# What books increase skills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've found a whole lot of libraries to 'borrow' from, but I'm not sure which books are worth stea..borrowing. Where can I find a list of books that increase skills when they are read? Preferably with their locations.

Comment: The wikia has a tiny list, which I assume will be populated as books are found. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_Book_(Skyrim)

Comment: Also, you can read skill books without stealing them, unless of course you wish to 'borrow' them for your own library.

Comment: Of course I would never steal a book, just borrow them and move them to my own residence until the owner asks for them back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.gamingreality.com/2011/11/skyrim-skill-book-locations-guide.html) is a website with all of the skill books listed by skill.

Answer (score 17):

For books in you inventory (or laying face up):

Books that increase a skill have that skill's icon on the cover

The full list of books including their locations can be found on the [Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_Book_(Skyrim))

Below is an except:

**Lockpicking**

- Advances in Lockpicking
- Proper Lock Design
- Surfeit of Thieves
- The Locked Room
- The Wolf Queen, v1

**One Handed**

- 2920, Morning Star, v1
- Fire and Darkness
- Mace Etiquette
- Night Falls on Sentinel
- The Importance of Where

**Pickpocket**

- Aevar Stone-Singer
- Beggar
- Guide to Better Thieving
- Purloined Shadows
- Thief

**Restoration**

- 2920, Rain's Hand, v4
- Mystery of Talara, v 2
- Racial Phylogeny
- The Exodus
- Withershins

**Smithing**

- Cherim's Heart of Anequina
- Heavy Armor Forging
- Light Armor Forging
- The Armorer's Challenge
- The Last Scabbard of Akrash

**Sneak**

- 2920, Last Seed, v8
- Legend of Krately House
- Sacred Witness
- The Red Kitchen Reader
- Three Thieves

**Speech**

- 2920, Second Seed, v5
- A Dance in Fire, v6
- A Dance in Fire, v7
- Biography of the Wolf Queen
- The Buying Game

**Twohanded**

- Battle of Sancre Tor
- King
- Song of Hrormir
- The Legendary City of Sancre Tor
- Words and Philosophy

**Multiple Skills**

- Oghma Infinium

Answer (score 11):

If the value is about 2 to 15 gold, ignore it.

If it is worth 50-70 gold, then read it - it's a skill book.

This does not take into account a few books that give you quests.