# Do you have to read an entire book to gain skills?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When reading [books to gain skills](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35112/what-books-increase-skills), do you have to read through the entire book to gain the skill, or will simply opening it give you the skill gain?

I haven't found any books that have given me any immediate benefits, so don't know if I haven't stumbled across any, or if I'm supposed to actually be paging through the whole thing.

Comment: One easy way to identify skill books is by their price.  Ordinary books tend to be <10, skill books tend to be 50+

Comment: @DavidFullerton you can also tell by name too, such as Advances in Lockpicking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you don't. You merely need to open the book to the first page.

You should read the whole thing though. The Lusty Argonian Maid is quite a ripping yarn.