# How to know what books will give you any skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What books increase skills?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35112/what-books-increase-skills)

There is a lot of books, I'm only interested in them for skills.

How to know what books will give you any skill?

Comment: Without looking it up I tend to judge them on their value. i.e. books worth 50 gold (or more) more often than not tend to level me up. The ones worth less don't.

Comment: Here: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skill_Book_(Skyrim)

Answer (score 3):

In short you can't. A certain rule of thumb might be that the more expensive book, the more likely it is to level you up. No guaranteed approach though. You should just go opening+closing the *interesting* books

Comment: expensive books has been very reliable for me

Comment: It's proven reliable for me as well. I do believe I've come across one expensive book which didn't give me a skill point, but it did give me a quest.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with above most books worth 25+ septums will have a chance at leveling a skill. (this is the same as it was in oblivion although the books tend to be worth less IMO) and it never hurts to try also if your a thief and you know about shadowmarks I have found many marked contain a book